# How can I create an mx record with openshift?

Tags: dns, openshift, mx-record

Openshift domain (example.com) requires a CNAME pointing to my example.rhcloud.com. However by doing this, and not allowing us to do an A record with IP they are breaking the ability to do an MX record for example.com since an MX record requires that example.com be an A name not a CNAME.

Is there a way around this? I'm using namecheap.

I've seen some hacky stuff to point to www.example.com but I don't want to do that, as I want to remove the www. from the domain.

Answer (score 2):

Its not possible with openshift, because `example.com` needs to point to an `A` record for `mx.example.com` to work properly. Its required by the RFC spec.

Because openshift requires you point `example.com` to a `CNAME` (foo-whatever.rhcloud.com), you cannot then point `mx.example.com` to an IP of email server and expect mail for `me@example.com` to work.

There are some hacky solutions, like using 3rd party dns resolver and cronjob to update the IP address of the openshift server, but none of these seem like solid solutions to me.

https://www.openshift.com/forums/openshift/methoddynamic-ip-for-your-apps-a-record

Answer (score 0):

OpenShift Online is not a dns provider, you can not create an mx record using it.  You would need to create an MX records at your dns provider for your domain.

If you mean "how can i create an mx record using my dns provider along with having a cname for openshift", then you would need to create an mx record that points to your third party mail service.

You can check out this answer (https://serverfault.com/questions/100064/dns-is-it-valid-to-have-an-mx-record-and-no-a-record) which should help you.

Comment: This does not work. I'm trying to create an mx record, but it requires that @ be pointed to an A name, not a CNAME as required by openshift.

Answer (score 0):

Some DNS providers support special types of DNS records that dynamically look up dynamic IP adresses and create the corresponding A records.

- [DNSimple](http://dnsimple.com) calls this an ALIAS record.
- [DNS Made Easy](http://www.dnsmadeeasy.com) calls it an ANAME record.

You can use these special record types instead of CNAME, if your DNS provider supports them.